# How to enable treemacs visibility on by default?

Tags: init-file, treemacs

I have treemacs setup and currently using `s-1` for toggle. But I would like to display the treemacs window always during startup. How to make it visible?

Comment: How about putting this somewhere in your `.emacs` / `init.el` file, save the file and restart Emacs?:  `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'treemacs)`  NOTE:  I could have used the `after-init-hook`, but `desktop.el` uses that hook (when said library is used), and the `emacs-startup-hook` is the last hook to load custom stuff when Emacs starts.  If by chance your `s-1` keyboard shortcut is not bound to the function `treemacs`, then substitute my example with whatever function you call with that keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Okay, I moved to spacemacs. A whole lot better now.